# Is Spark only applying my UDF on records being shown?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a feeling Spark is being cleverer than me and reordering (or at least in comparison to the written code) what is running on executors etc.

Suppose I have a very simple spark query in scala as follows.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val rawData = sqlContext.sql("FROM mytable SELECT *")
```

I then create a new column using some functionality in a UDF, this function is not lightweight (or at least some of the time) and relies on multiple columns in the data. Roughly speaking my UDF looks similar to this although the processing is only an example.

```
def method1(s1:String, s2:String):String = {
  List(s1, s2).mkString(" ")
}

val method1UDF = udf(method1 _)

val dataWithCol = rawData
                  .withColumn("newcol", method1UDF($"c1",$"c2"))

dataWithCol.show(100)
```

My question actually revolves around the last statement, or at least I think it does.

If my dataset has 1 billion records in it, is Spark actually only applying my withColumn to 100 records, or is it applying it to all 1 million records and then just returning the first 100?

In Hive I presume the equivalent would be:

```
SELECT t.c1, t.c2, CONCAT_WS(" ",t.c1,t.c2) as newCol from (
    SELECT c1,c2 as newCol FROM mytable limit 100
) t
```

Even though in code it looks like i've written the equivalent of the following query

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT c1,c2, CONCAT_WS(" ",c1,c2) as newCol FROM mytable  
) t limit 100
```

I suspect it is doing the former since adding a filter on the new column drastically slows down the operation.  If I change the last line to:

```
dataWithCol.filter($"newCol" === "H i").show(100)
```

This is now having to apply the function to a lot more data (presumably the entire dataset) before it does the limit of 100, similar to the following Hive query:

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT c1,c2, CONCAT_WS(" ",c1,c2) as newCol FROM mytable  
) t where t.newCol == "H i" limit 100
```

Am I along the right lines with what Spark is doing in the background?  Is it optimising my query by only applying the processing on records which will end up being viewed?

Comment: Hint: check "explain" result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure you can alway make an experiment:

```
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1490732267478).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val rawData = spark.range(0, 1000000000, 1, 1000)
  .toDF("id")
  .select(
    $"id".cast("string").alias("s1"), 
    $"id".cast("string").alias("s2"))

val counter = sc.longAccumulator("counter")

def f = udf((s1: String, s2: String) => {
  counter.add(1)
  s"$s1 $s2"
})

rawData.select(f($"s1", $"s2")).show(10)



// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
```

```
+-----------+
|UDF(s1, s2)|
+-----------+
|        0 0|
|        1 1|
|        2 2|
|        3 3|
|        4 4|
|        5 5|
|        6 6|
|        7 7|
|        8 8|
|        9 9|
+-----------+
only showing top 10 rows

rawData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [s1: string, s2: string]
counter: org.apache.spark.util.LongAccumulator = LongAccumulator(id: 0, name: Some(counter), value: 12)
f: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

scala> counter.value
res1: Long = 12
```

As you can see Spark limits the number of records to be processed but it is not exactly precise. You should also remember that these results are version and query dependent.

For example earlier Spark version where fairly limited when applying optimizations to UDF calls. Also upstream wide transformation may affect this behavior and result in processing more (or even all) records.

Answer (score 1):

Spark applies something known as "lazy execution". This means it only evaluates actions as and when necessary. So, it is actually doing something between the two statements you wrote. The execution planner is clever enough to figure out what needs to be done, and what doesn't. To see more detail browse to localhost:4040 (increment port by 1 for every context you're running).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both helped me figure out what was going on but can only select one as the answer.